# How to avoid loading dlls from GAC for referenced packages?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, devexpress

I have been tasked with upgrading DevExpress packages for one of our applications. We have some third party libraries that use older versions of DevExpress. So, after upgrading the DevExpress now multiple versions of the DevExpress dlls are getting loaded. Newer ones are loaded by the application code and older ones are loaded by the third party dlls causing UI to behave in weird ways. Is there a way to make sure that only latest versions of the packages are loaded even by third party libraries?

I did try using strong type names but that does not prevent third party libraries to load older packages.

Comment: You can try [assembly redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions), but it might not work. The best option is to get a new version of the third party dll, second best is to stick with the DevExpress version you have.